# Hibernate/JPA ManyToOne mapping with overlapping column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Note: This is for a legacy project, I can't change everything to generated surrogate IDs.

I have an Entities with Embedded compound keys, with an entity ID and a client ID.

```
@Embeddable
public class EntityId {
  @Column(name=COL_EID)
  @NotNull
  private String eid;

  @Column(name=COL_CID)
  private String cid;
}

@Entity
public class Customer {

  @Id @Embedded @Valid
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name=EntityId.FIELD_EID, column=@Column(name=COL_EID)),
    @AttributeOverride(name=EntityId.FIELD_CID, column=@Column(name=COL_CID))
  })
  private EntityId id;

  // Other stuff
}

@Entity
public class MyNewOrder {

  @Id @Embedded @Valid
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name=EntityId.FIELD_EID, column=@Column(name=COL_EID)),
    @AttributeOverride(name=EntityId.FIELD_CID, column=@Column(name=COL_CID))
  })
  private EntityId id;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, optional = false)
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "customer_EID", referencedColumnName = "EID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "CID", referencedColumnName = "CID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
  private Customer customer;
}
```

So this was a minimal sample of what's happening. I want to have the Customer EID in my "MyNewOrder" table, but the CID to overlap, i.e.:

MyNewOrder: [EID, CID, customer_EID]

The the whole method is a bit complicated, but it goes something like this:

```
@In Session session;

public void myMethod() {
  Transaction t = null;       
  try {
    t = session.beginTransaction();

    Customer c = (Customer) session.get(Customer.class, "the ID");
    MyNewOrder order = new MyNewOrder();
    order.setCustomer(c);
    session.persist(order);

    t.commit();
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  t.rollback();
}
```

This is running on JBoss AS 7.1, using Hibernate 4.2.
In the Debugger everything looks A-OK, I find the right Customer, all IDs are set, I don't get any exceptions, but in the Database I get a row:

> MyNewOrder[eid1, cid1, NULL]

EDIT:
It works when I remove the `@JoinColumns` completely, but then I need to add a superfluous 'customer_CID' column.

Comment: `1.`  maybe try to remove try catch to see if there is any error `2.` maybe try to change `insertable = false, updatable = false` to `true` . `3.` set hibernate to verbose debug mode to see the generate query

Comment: I agree with oak above; just to clarify though, try to set `insertable = true, updatable = true` *only* in the `@JoinColumn(name = "customer_EID")`. This way JPA will (hopefully) update the `customer_EID` column of the relationship and *not* the `CID` column, which is shared with the PK.

Comment: As for `2.` I get an Exception: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed` and if I remove them for both columns I get `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: at.mycompany.MyNewOrder column: CID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Comment: As for `1.`, In reality the classes are waaay more complicated and they also inherti from a common EntityBase. MyNewOrder has the inherited fields, one simple field and two ManyToOne, one OneToMany. I can see an insert of all the inherited and the simple (integer) one. The three remaining ones are NULL, but it's a similar situation with the CID field. Also I'd like to get the simplest case working first.